# Why do I get that point in my Flutter AnimatedChecked? (CustomPaint)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, web, dart

**Disclaimer**:

- Flutter Beta - 1.19
- Flutter Web on *Chrome*

Greetings to all Flutter devs :)

I got a solution for an Animated Checked Widgets (originally by: [Raul Mateo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6245043/raul-mateo)), which I have improved to behave and look better.

But I am not a CustomPaint expert, so I don't know in the following code, why I am getting that green point in the turn of the checked line:

### Bug

[image]

### Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:angles/angles.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:core';

class AnimatedCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  final double size;
  final Color color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final VoidCallback onComplete;

  const AnimatedCheck({
    this.size = 80.0,
    this.onComplete,
    this.strokeWidth = 2.5,
    this.color = Colors.green,
  });

  @override
  _AnimatedCheckState createState() => _AnimatedCheckState();
}

class _AnimatedCheckState extends State<AnimatedCheck> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> curve;
  bool completed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
    curve = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.decelerate);

    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed && widget.onComplete != null) {
        widget.onComplete();
      }
      if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        completed = true;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: [
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
          height: widget.size,
          width: widget.size,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            border: Border.all(
              width: widget.strokeWidth,
              color: completed ? widget.color : widget.color.withOpacity(.05),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: widget.size - widget.strokeWidth,
          width: widget.size - widget.strokeWidth,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: CheckPainter(
              value: curve.value,
              color: widget.color,
              strokeWidth: widget.strokeWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class CheckPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Paint _paint;
  double value;
  Color color;
  double strokeWidth;

  double _length;
  double _offset;
  double _secondOffset;
  double _startingAngle;

  CheckPainter({
    this.value,
    this.color,
    this.strokeWidth,
  }) {
    _paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    assert(value != null);

    _length = 60;
    _offset = 0;
    _startingAngle = 205;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Background canvas
    var rect = Offset(0, 0) & size;
    _paint.color = color.withOpacity(0);

    double line1x1 = size.width / 2 + size.width * cos(Angle.fromDegrees(_startingAngle).radians) * .5;
    double line1y1 = size.height / 2 + size.height * sin(Angle.fromDegrees(_startingAngle).radians) * .5;
    double line1x2 = size.width * .45;
    double line1y2 = size.height * .65;

    double line2x1 = size.width / 2 + size.width * cos(Angle.fromDegrees(320).radians) * .35;
    double line2y1 = size.height / 2 + size.height * sin(Angle.fromDegrees(320).radians) * .35;

    canvas.drawArc(rect, Angle.fromDegrees(_startingAngle).radians, Angle.fromDegrees(360).radians, false, _paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(line1x1, line1y1), Offset(line1x2, line1y2), _paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(line2x1, line2y1), Offset(line1x2, line1y2), _paint);

    // animation painter

    double circleValue, checkValue;
    if (value < .5) {
      checkValue = 0;
      circleValue = value / .5;
    } else {
      checkValue = (value - .5) / .5;
      circleValue = 1;
    }

    _paint.color = color;
    double firstAngle = _startingAngle + 360 * circleValue;
    double line1Value = 0, line2Value = 0;

    canvas.drawArc(rect, Angle.fromDegrees(firstAngle).radians,
        Angle.fromDegrees(getSecondAngle(firstAngle, _length, _startingAngle + 360)).radians, false, _paint);

    if (circleValue >= 1) {
      if (checkValue < .5) {
        line2Value = 0;
        line1Value = checkValue / .5;
      } else {
        line2Value = (checkValue - .55) / .55;
        line1Value = .75;
      }
    }

    double auxLine1x1 = (line1x2 - line1x1) * getMin(line1Value, .8);
    double auxLine1y1 = (((auxLine1x1) - line1x1) / (line1x2 - line1x1)) * (line1y2 - line1y1) + line1y1;

    if (_offset < 60) {
      auxLine1x1 = line1x1;
      auxLine1y1 = line1y1;
    }

    double auxLine1x2 = auxLine1x1 + _offset / 2;
    double auxLine1y2 = (((auxLine1x1 + _offset / 2) - line1x1) / (line1x2 - line1x1)) * (line1y2 - line1y1) + line1y1;

    if (checkIfPointHasCrossedLine(
        Offset(line1x2, line1y2), Offset(line2x1, line2y1), Offset(auxLine1x2, auxLine1y2))) {
      auxLine1x2 = line1x2;
      auxLine1y2 = line1y2;
    }

    if (_offset > 0) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(auxLine1x1, auxLine1y1), Offset(auxLine1x2, auxLine1y2), _paint);
    }

    // SECOND LINE

    double auxLine2x1 = (line2x1 - line1x2) * line2Value;
    double auxLine2y1 =
        ((((line2x1 - line1x2) * line2Value) - line1x2) / (line2x1 - line1x2)) * (line2y1 - line1y2) + line1y2;

    if (checkIfPointHasCrossedLine(
        Offset(line1x1, line1y1), Offset(line1x2, line1y2), Offset(auxLine2x1, auxLine2y1))) {
      auxLine2x1 = line1x2;
      auxLine2y1 = line1y2;
    }
    if (line2Value > 0) {
      canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(auxLine2x1, auxLine2y1),
          Offset(
              (line2x1 - line1x2) * line2Value + _offset * .75,
              ((((line2x1 - line1x2) * line2Value + _offset * .75) - line1x2) / (line2x1 - line1x2)) *
                      (line2y1 - line1y2) +
                  line1y2),
          _paint);
    }
  }

  double getMax(double x, double y) {
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
  }

  double getMin(double x, double y) {
    return (x > y) ? y : x;
  }

  bool checkIfPointHasCrossedLine(Offset a, Offset b, Offset point) {
    return ((b.dx - a.dx) * (point.dy - a.dy) - (b.dy - a.dy) * (point.dx - a.dx)) > 0;
  }

  double getSecondAngle(double angle, double plus, double max) {
    if (angle + plus > max) {
      _offset = angle + plus - max;
      return max - angle;
    } else {
      _offset = 0;
      return plus;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CheckPainter old) {
    return old.value != value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this has to do with the web implementation of drawArc, the following code draws nothing on ios but draws a point on web:

```dart
 canvas.drawArc(rect, 0, 0, false, _paint);
```

You can try to conditionally draw the arc

```dart
    if (circleValue < 1)
      canvas.drawArc(
          rect,
          Angle.fromDegrees(firstAngle).radians,
          Angle.fromDegrees(
                  getSecondAngle(firstAngle, _length, _startingAngle + 360))
              .radians,
          false,
          _paint);
```

but first you would like to to move the `_offset`update from `getSecondAngle(...)` to its own function, since it's two separate concerns

```dart
  double getUpdatedOffset(double angle, double plus, double max) =>
      angle + plus > max ? angle + plus - max : 0;
```

and call it after the conditional drawArc

```dart
    _offset = getUpdatedOffset(firstAngle, _length, _startingAngle + 360);
```

full updated code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:angles/angles.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:core';

class AnimatedCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  final double size;
  final Color color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final VoidCallback onComplete;

  const AnimatedCheck({
    this.size = 80.0,
    this.onComplete,
    this.strokeWidth = 2.5,
    this.color = Colors.green,
  });

  @override
  _AnimatedCheckState createState() => _AnimatedCheckState();
}

class _AnimatedCheckState extends State<AnimatedCheck>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> curve;
  bool completed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);
    curve = CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.decelerate);

    _controller.addListener(() {
      if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed &&
          widget.onComplete != null) {
        widget.onComplete();
      }
      if (_controller.status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
        completed = true;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      children: [
        AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
          height: widget.size,
          width: widget.size,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            border: Border.all(
              width: widget.strokeWidth,
              color: completed ? widget.color : widget.color.withOpacity(.05),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: widget.size - widget.strokeWidth,
          width: widget.size - widget.strokeWidth,
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: CheckPainter(
              value: curve.value,
              color: widget.color,
              strokeWidth: widget.strokeWidth,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class CheckPainter extends CustomPainter {
  Paint _paint;
  double value;
  Color color;
  double strokeWidth;

  double _length;
  double _offset;
  double _secondOffset;
  double _startingAngle;

  CheckPainter({
    this.value,
    this.color,
    this.strokeWidth,
  }) {
    _paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    assert(value != null);

    _length = 60;
    _offset = 0;
    _startingAngle = 205;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    // Background canvas
    var rect = Offset(0, 0) & size;
    _paint.color = color.withOpacity(0);

    double line1x1 = size.width / 2 +
        size.width * cos(Angle.fromDegrees(_startingAngle).radians) * .5;
    double line1y1 = size.height / 2 +
        size.height * sin(Angle.fromDegrees(_startingAngle).radians) * .5;
    double line1x2 = size.width * .45;
    double line1y2 = size.height * .65;

    double line2x1 =
        size.width / 2 + size.width * cos(Angle.fromDegrees(320).radians) * .35;
    double line2y1 = size.height / 2 +
        size.height * sin(Angle.fromDegrees(320).radians) * .35;

    canvas.drawArc(rect, Angle.fromDegrees(_startingAngle).radians,
        Angle.fromDegrees(360).radians, false, _paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(line1x1, line1y1), Offset(line1x2, line1y2), _paint);
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(line2x1, line2y1), Offset(line1x2, line1y2), _paint);

    // animation painter

    double circleValue, checkValue;
    if (value < .5) {
      checkValue = 0;
      circleValue = value / .5;
    } else {
      checkValue = (value - .5) / .5;
      circleValue = 1;
    }

    _paint.color = color;
    double firstAngle = _startingAngle + 360 * circleValue;
    double line1Value = 0, line2Value = 0;

    if (circleValue < 1)
      canvas.drawArc(
          rect,
          Angle.fromDegrees(firstAngle).radians,
          Angle.fromDegrees(
                  getSecondAngle(firstAngle, _length, _startingAngle + 360))
              .radians,
          false,
          _paint);

    _offset = getUpdatedOffset(firstAngle, _length, _startingAngle + 360);

    if (circleValue >= 1) {
      if (checkValue < .5) {
        line2Value = 0;
        line1Value = checkValue / .5;
      } else {
        line2Value = (checkValue - .55) / .55;
        line1Value = .75;
      }
    }

    double auxLine1x1 = (line1x2 - line1x1) * getMin(line1Value, .8);
    double auxLine1y1 =
        (((auxLine1x1) - line1x1) / (line1x2 - line1x1)) * (line1y2 - line1y1) +
            line1y1;

    if (_offset < 60) {
      auxLine1x1 = line1x1;
      auxLine1y1 = line1y1;
    }

    double auxLine1x2 = auxLine1x1 + _offset / 2;
    double auxLine1y2 =
        (((auxLine1x1 + _offset / 2) - line1x1) / (line1x2 - line1x1)) *
                (line1y2 - line1y1) +
            line1y1;

    if (checkIfPointHasCrossedLine(Offset(line1x2, line1y2),
        Offset(line2x1, line2y1), Offset(auxLine1x2, auxLine1y2))) {
      auxLine1x2 = line1x2;
      auxLine1y2 = line1y2;
    }

    if (_offset > 0) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(auxLine1x1, auxLine1y1),
          Offset(auxLine1x2, auxLine1y2), _paint);
    }

    // SECOND LINE

    double auxLine2x1 = (line2x1 - line1x2) * line2Value;
    double auxLine2y1 =
        ((((line2x1 - line1x2) * line2Value) - line1x2) / (line2x1 - line1x2)) *
                (line2y1 - line1y2) +
            line1y2;

    if (checkIfPointHasCrossedLine(Offset(line1x1, line1y1),
        Offset(line1x2, line1y2), Offset(auxLine2x1, auxLine2y1))) {
      auxLine2x1 = line1x2;
      auxLine2y1 = line1y2;
    }
    if (line2Value > 0) {
      canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(auxLine2x1, auxLine2y1),
          Offset(
              (line2x1 - line1x2) * line2Value + _offset * .75,
              ((((line2x1 - line1x2) * line2Value + _offset * .75) - line1x2) /
                          (line2x1 - line1x2)) *
                      (line2y1 - line1y2) +
                  line1y2),
          _paint);
    }
  }

  double getMax(double x, double y) {
    return (x > y) ? x : y;
  }

  double getMin(double x, double y) {
    return (x > y) ? y : x;
  }

  bool checkIfPointHasCrossedLine(Offset a, Offset b, Offset point) {
    return ((b.dx - a.dx) * (point.dy - a.dy) -
            (b.dy - a.dy) * (point.dx - a.dx)) >
        0;
  }

  double getSecondAngle(double angle, double plus, double max) =>
      angle + plus > max ? max - angle : plus;

  double getUpdatedOffset(double angle, double plus, double max) =>
      angle + plus > max ? angle + plus - max : 0;

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CheckPainter old) {
    return old.value != value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you sooo much @MDemetrio :)! Worked like a charm! How did you knew that? Always these extras for web-platform ^^

Comment: I didn't knew that too!haha, I just ran your code on ios and saw that the point was not being drawn.
We should probably file an issue on flutter's github about this, on android the point is not drawn also.